# SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL refusing connection to 'localhost' after connecting to AWS RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, pymysql

```
try:
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql:///mysqladmin:***@***.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/peopledb')
    print "Opened database successfully";

except Exception as e:
    print("Error during connection: ", str(e))

print engine.table_names()
```

I am attempting to use SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL to connect to a database in AWS RDS.  The above code errors on the final line, when I access engine.table_names().  The error I receive is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)")
```

Obviously I am not trying to connect to my localhost, I am connecting/connected to a remote host.

Also I was able to successfully connect and access the database using native PyMySQL commands, this issue has to do with SQLAlchemy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb.

There is an extra forward-slash (/) in my connection string that was ruining it. :(

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Consider deleting this post as it is just a typographic error and not useful for future readers.

Comment: ^ I disagree. This very much helped me with the exact same issue! Can't believe that was it.